# scanf не выполняется. Простой калькулятор

Tags: c, switch, scanf

Это код простого калькулятора на *switch* и *case*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int n1,n2;
    char op;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    printf("Введите два числа: ");
    scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);

    printf("Выберите операцию '+,-,*,/' ");
    scanf("%c",&op);

    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%d + %d = %d",n1,n2,(n1+n2));
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%d - %d = %d",n1,n2,(n1-n2));
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%d * %d = %d",n1,n2,(n1*n2));
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%d / %d = %d",n1,n2,(n1/n2));
            break;
        default:
            printf("Такой математической операции не существует!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но, когда я запускаю, он просит два числа. Естественно, ввожу, и он их принимает (убедился в этом, когда проводил **debug**). Но, когда дело доходит до выбора мат. операции, он не даёт вводить и сразу говорит, что такой операции не существует.

Comment: @andreymal, ничего не поменялось. поставил пробел, и всё равно работает. даже без пробела. но ошибка осталась

Comment: @andreymal, там пробел действительно не нужен, хотя и не вреден. А вот отсутствие пробела перед `%c` - проблема. [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): "`scanf(" %c", &c);` // consume all consecutive whitespace after %d, then read a char".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
printf("Выберите операцию '+,-,*,/' ");
scanf("\n%c",&op);
```

Просто у вас считывается в `op` символ перевода строки.

Comment: Введите два числа: 10 5
Выберите операцию '+,-,*,/' +
10 + 5 = 15. Получилось. Спасибо

Comment: Ещё я заметил, что когда первым спрашиваешь операцию, а потом число, всё работает без символа перевода строки! Си такой капризный

Comment: Потому что тогда оставшийся `\n` пропускается в поисках **числа**. Он не может быть числом, но вот символом — запросто. И это не капризность, а точно описанное поведение.

Comment: Для калькуляторов принято использовать Decimal floating point (DFP), там своя математика и функции ввода/вывода. Чаще всего поиском находится уже готовый калькулятор на DFP числах, в виде собранной библиотеки. Просто используй готовое.